React Native's useNavigation hook inside of a custom hook in typescript
I want to create a custom hook using useNavigation from @react-navigation.
I'm trying to do it with TypeScript, but I'm facing some issues with types. How can I resolve this when encountering the following situation?
type RootStackParamList = {
  Login: { page: string } | undefined;
  Foo: { mode: string };
  Bar: undefined;
};

const useAuthNavigation = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>();

  const navigate = (
    page: keyof RootStackParamList,
    params?: RootStackParamList[keyof RootStackParamList],
  ) => {
    navigation.navigate(page, params);
  };

  return { navigate };
};
export default useAuthNavigation;

The error I'm encountering is with the type of navigation.navigate(page, params);,
and the error message is as follows:

Argument of type '[keyof RootStackParamList, { page: string; } | { mode: string; } | undefined]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[screen: "Login"] | [screen: "Login", params: { page: string; } | undefined] | [screen: "Foo", params: { mode: string; }] | [screen: "Bar"] | [screen: "Bar", params: undefined]'.
Type '[keyof RootStackParamList, { page: string; } | { mode: string; } | undefined]' is not assignable to type '[screen: "Login", params: { page: string; } | undefined] | [screen: "Foo", params: { mode: string; }] | [screen: "Bar", params: undefined]'.
Type '[keyof RootStackParamList, { page: string; } | { mode: string; } | undefined]' is not assignable to type '[screen: "Bar", params: undefined]'.
Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
Type 'keyof RootStackParamList' is not assignable to type '"Bar"'.
Type '"Login"' is not assignable to type '"Bar"'.ts(2345)


I thought hooks could only be used in components?  Do you really need the custom hook? I have a configuration that uses useNavigation with TypeScript...it's actually quite simple.

@Alex
I want to create a hook that can be easily called from multiple components to navigate between screens. Even if it's used within components, specifying the page for each menu might lead to a lot of repetitive code. For example, navigation.navigate('Foo'), navigation.navigate('Boo'). However, if I turn the above into a function, I could receive the page as a parameter and handle it with navigation.navigate(page).

Yeah i know what you mean...I had exactly the same problem - but what I did was create a navigation service class which took the NavigationProp as a parameter. I then just passed this service around. Something like that might work.
